# Update JSON using JSON_MODIFY

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-json

I store JSON data in SQL Server.

My table looks like:

Table name: JsonData

Columns: ID, Data

My JSON looks like:

```
{
    "data": [{
            "identifier": 1,
            "someData": {
                "sample1": "lorem 1",
                "sample2": "test 1"
            }
        },
        {
            "identifier": 2,
            "someData": {
                "sample1": "lorem 2",
                "sample2": "test 2"
            }
        },
        {
            "identifier": 3,
            "someData": {
                "sample1": "lorem 3",
                "sample2": "test 3"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to use JSON_MODIFY to update e.g sample1 for identifier 3.
How can I access to sample1 and modify it?

Comment: Is this a JSON with a fixed structure - always `identifier`, `someData` and `sample1` and `sample2`?

Comment: SomeData can be different, but identifier is constant and I'd like to use it as key

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: @Zhorov SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Example:**

Your `JSON` is an array of `JSON` objects, so you need an index to access each element. In this case, one possible approach is to use an expression as `path` [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments) for `JSON_MODIFY`. Note, that this feature is available in SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and in Azure SQL Database. The `JSON` array is splitted into elements using [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#return-value) with default schema and in this case the returned columns are `key`, `value` and `type`.

**Basic example:**

Statement:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
    "data": [{
            "identifier": 1,
            "someData": {
                "sample1": "lorem 1",
                "sample2": "test 1"
            }
        },
        {
            "identifier": 2,
            "someData": {
                "sample1": "lorem 2",
                "sample2": "test 2"
            }
        },
        {
            "identifier": 3,
            "someData": {
                "sample1": "lorem 3",
                "sample2": "test 3"
            }
        }
    ]
}'

SELECT JSON_MODIFY(@json, '$.data[' + j.[key] + '].someData.sample1', N'NewValue') AS JsonData
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.data') j
WHERE JSON_VALUE([value], '$.identifier') = 3
```

Output:

```
----------------------------
JsonData
----------------------------
{
    "data": [{
            "identifier": 1,
            "someData": {
                "sample1": "lorem 1",
                "sample2": "test 1"
            }
        },
        {
            "identifier": 2,
            "someData": {
                "sample1": "lorem 2",
                "sample2": "test 2"
            }
        },
        {
            "identifier": 3,
            "someData": {
                "sample1": "NewValue",
                "sample2": "test 3"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Table example:**

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
  ID int,
  Data nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
   (ID, Data)
VALUES
   (1, N'{
    "data": [{
            "identifier": 1,
            "someData": {
                "sample1": "lorem 1",
                "sample2": "test 1"
            }
        },
        {
            "identifier": 2,
            "someData": {
                "sample1": "lorem 2",
                "sample2": "test 2"
            }
        },
        {
            "identifier": 3,
            "someData": {
                "sample1": "lorem 3",
                "sample2": "test 3"
            }
        }
    ]
}'),
   (2, N'{
    "data": [{
            "identifier": 1,
            "someData": {
                "sample1": "lorem 1",
                "sample2": "test 1"
            }
        },
        {
            "identifier": 2,
            "someData": {
                "sample1": "lorem 2",
                "sample2": "test 2"
            }
        },
        {
            "identifier": 3,
            "someData": {
                "sample1": "lorem 3",
                "sample2": "test 3"
            }
        }
    ]
}')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   d.ID, c.Data
FROM #Data d
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT JSON_MODIFY(d.Data, N'$.data[' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), j.[key] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS) + N'].someData.sample1', N'NewValue') AS Data
   FROM OPENJSON(d.Data, '$.data') j
   WHERE JSON_VALUE([value], '$.identifier') = 3
) c
```

Notes:

The `key` column has a BIN2 collation, so you need to convert with collate option.

Comment: A way to avoid the ugly collation stuff: `FORMATMESSAGE(N'$.data[%s].someData.sample1', j.[key])`.

Comment: If we have multiple updates, the select is giving the multiple rows. How can I get the updated  single JSON object after modifying.