# How to use JSON_MODIFY to update keys in a column with JSON data

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Is it possible to change the JSON key with `JSON_MODIFY`?

Using the data example shown here, I wish to change the key (not the value) in column `JsonData`. One of the rows of data has the key of `Day`, while the other row has the key of `DayOfWeek`.

I'd like to update the one row and change the key from `Day` to `DayOfWeek`. The end result is this table should have JSON data where all the rows have keys `DayOfWeek` and `Time`.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE TempTbl 
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    JsonData nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO TempTbl (JsonData)
VALUES 
   ('[{"Day":1,"Time":6},{"Day":2,"Time":11},{"Day":3,"Time":16}]'),
   ('[{"DayOfWeek":0,"Time":6},{"DayOfWeek":1,"Time":6}]')
```

Sample `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    JSonData,
    [Day],
    [DayOfWeek],
    [Time]
FROM 
    TempTbl
CROSS APPLY 
    OPENJSON(JsonData)
    WITH (  
          [Day] int '$.Day',
          [DayOfWeek] int '$.DayOfWeek',
          [Time] int '$.Time'
         )
WHERE
    [Day] IS NOT NULL
```

Expected result for new data that lives inside `TempTbl.JsonData` column:

```
   ('[{"DayOfWeek":1,"Time":6},{"DayOfWeek":2,"Time":11},{"DayOfWeek":3,"Time":16}]'),
   ('[{"DayOfWeek":0,"Time":6},{"DayOfWeek":1,"Time":6}]')
```

I attempted `JSON_Modify` to no avail. Mainly because the JSON data to change is key elements inside an array, this is more difficult to resolve.

This seems close and may work with some modification:
[Update JSON using JSON_MODIFY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57107947/update-json-using-json-modify)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

Because JSON value is a plain `NVARCHAR(...)` data type, a regular `REPLACE()` function call does the job.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, JsonData NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (JsonData) VALUES 
(N'[{"Day":1,"Time":6},{"Day":2,"Time":11},{"Day":3,"Time":16}]'),
(N'[{"DayOfWeek":0,"Time":6},{"DayOfWeek":1,"Time":6}]');

UPDATE @tbl
SET JsonData = REPLACE(JsonData, '"Day"', '"DayOfWeek"');

-- test
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

| ID | JsonData |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"DayOfWeek":1,"Time":6},{"DayOfWeek":2,"Time":11},{"DayOfWeek":3,"Time":16}] |
| 2 | [{"DayOfWeek":0,"Time":6},{"DayOfWeek":1,"Time":6}] |